# Nginx Frontend And Backend under url

Tags: nginx

I have this nginx configuration:

```
server{
    listen      80;
    server_name     hans.site.dev;

    location / {
        index       index.html index.php;
        root    /var/www/a/public;
    }

    location /api {
        root /var/www/b/public;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /api/$uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include     fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

where:

- A : frontend (angular)
- B : backend (lumen)

and later i want to add

- C : administrator (angular)
- D : support (angular)

but even for this configuration, when i try to access **hans.site.dev/api/**, it will give me this error:
"/var/www/***a***/public/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.56.1, server: hans.site.dev, request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", host: "hans.site.dev".

why it refer to ***a*** instead of ***b***? and how to fix it?

Comment: Note that now your `/api` location looks for files like that:
`/var/www/b/public/api`. You should use `alias` in that case.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

So you get redirected to `/index.php?$query_string;`

Answer (score 1):

Your `try_files` statement is incorrect.

- Inside the `location /api` block, the `$uri` variable already contains the `/api` prefix.
- The default action currently sends the client to some other `index.php` and not the desired location `/api/index.php`

Try this:

```
location /api {
    root /var/www/b/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php?$query_string;
```

With this configuration, all files are located in the directory structure:

```
/var/www/b/public/api/
```

Note that `/api` is the final directory component.

EDIT: If you must use the `alias` directive, note this [open issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) regarding the use of `try_files`. So your `try_files` functions need to reimplemented using `if` statements. Note [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of the `if` directive.

The `root` is replaced by `alias` and `try_files` is replaced by discrete `if` statements. The contents of the `if` block is limited, so we use `rewrite ... last` statements only.

The `index` directive is implemented using multiple `if` statements (are they all really necessary). There may be a better way of doing that.

The `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is set to `$request_filename` which is the aliased pathname.

```
location /api {
    alias /var/www/b/public;

    if (-f $request_filename/index.php) { rewrite ^ $uri/index.php last; }
    if (-f $request_filename/index.html) { rewrite ^ $uri/index.html last; }
    if (-f $request_filename/index.htm) { rewrite ^ $uri/index.htm last; }
    if (!-f $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /api/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include     fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: failed, is this really make /api refer to /var/www/b/public? because my endpoint is /api/index.php = /var/www/b/public/index.php.

Comment: Trying to alias a PHP application from `/api` to `/public` can be done, but is quite complex. The simplest solution is to rename/move the directory.

Comment: rename or move is not allowed, i am looking for the real solution because we have several of this and i have to try several configurations

Comment: OK, I have updated the answer with a working `alias` solution. Hopefully it meets your edge conditions.

Comment: still no luck, i still get the /api to refer to /a instead of /b